# Application crashes with Timeout Exception, Interrupted IO Exception Retrofit 2 android

Tags: android, exception, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using the below code:

```
 // customize client for first Retrofit instance for Client Id and Secret
    private val customOkHttpClient: OkHttpClient = baseOkHttpClient
        .newBuilder()
        .followRedirects(false)
        .build()

    val retrofitInstance: Retrofit?
        get() {
            if (retrofit == null) {
                val client = customOkHttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
                        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                            try {
                                val request = chain.request()
                                    .newBuilder()
                                    .addHeader("Id", "")
                                    .addHeader("Key", "")
                                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                    .build()
                                return chain.proceed(request)
                            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                                when (exception) {
                                    is SocketTimeoutException -> {
                                        val message = handler.obtainMessage()
                                        //message.sendToTarget()
                                    }
                                    is SocketException -> {
                                        val message = handler.obtainMessage()
                                        //message.sendToTarget()
                                    }
                                    is IOException -> {
                                        val message = handler.obtainMessage()
                                        // message.sendToTarget()
                                    }
                                    else -> exception.stackTrace
                                }
                                return onOnIntercept(chain)
                            }

                        }

                    }).connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                    .build()


                retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build()
            }
            return retrofit

        }
```

My onOnIntercept Method:

```
 @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun onOnIntercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        try {
            val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
            val content = response.body().toString()
            return response.newBuilder()
                .body(ResponseBody.create(response.body()!!.contentType(), content)).build()
        } catch (exception: SocketTimeoutException) {
            exception.printStackTrace()

      val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
        if (response.isSuccessful)
            return response
        else
            response.close()

        return response
    }
```

I am getting exception when the application is running on low internet speed, timeout occurs etc
PFB the exception:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-6
    Process: , PID: 30308
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.java:656)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:664)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:131)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at $retrofitSocialLoginInstance$1.intercept(InjectorUtils.kt:191)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Please do let me know how can I avoid application crash in all scenarios

Comment: did you check with increasing time?

Comment: @Sajith Yes how can I find a correct time, increasing time is not a correct fix right?

Comment: A bit late but how did you manage to resolve this issue?